# Xcode 11 not recognizing static library's architecture: MacCatalyst (aka UIKitForMac)

Tags: ios, macos, static-libraries, uikitformac, mac-catalyst

After getting excited about 2019's WWDC announcements, I tried compiling my existing iOS app against the MacOS using Xcode 11.0 beta. Unfortunately, it didn't go as expected.

Xcode says my static library is built for < unknown > architecture:

> Building for UIKit for Mac, but the linked library 'libssl.a' was
>   built for < unknown >. You may need to restrict the platforms for which
>   this library should be linked in the target editor.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

But when I check my static libs, I can see they do contain the desired architecture `x86_64`:
[image]

I believe this issue may be related to an Xcode Beta bug. Does anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: “Xcode says my static library is built for < unknown > architecture“ No it doesn’t. It says platform.  And  it says you have too many, not too few.

Comment: There is a possible solution here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117346. edford, software engineer from apple says: *Libraries built for the iOS simulator with previous versions of Xcode need to be rebuilt with Xcode 11 for the Project Catalyst environment specifically for the Mac -- there are differences in the compiled product, and a build for the iOS simulator is not sufficient.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### One-line fix:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.git --branch feature/mac-catalyst && \
cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone && \
./build-libssl.sh --archs="MacOSX_x86_64 i386 arm64 armv7s armv7"
```

### Explanation:

According to **edford**, Apple's software engineer, we need to build our binaries for the iOS platform, targeting `MacOSX` and use the `CFLAG` `-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi`. There is a very enlightening discussion here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/362577.

I've forked OpenSSL-for-iPhone [here](https://github.com/marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) and implemented MacCatalyst support in the branch `feature/mac-catalyst`.

You can build it for `MacCatalyst` either by specifying `archs` or `targets`:

#### Option `--archs`, for OpenSSL <= 1.0.2:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.git --branch feature/mac-catalyst && \
cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone && \
./build-libssl.sh --archs="MacOSX_x86_64 i386 arm64 armv7s armv7"  --version="1.0.2l"
```

#### Option `--targets` for OpenSSL >= 1.1.0

```sh
git clone git@github.com:marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.git --branch feature/mac-catalyst && \
cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone && \
./build-libssl.sh --targets="ios-sim-cross-i386 ios64-cross-arm64 ios-cross-armv7s ios-cross-armv7 mac-catalyst-x86_64" --version="1.1.0"
```

Comment: Would you be able to share your OpenSSL library that's built for UIKitForMac? Having trouble building it on my machine.

Comment: Hey @bmueller, I've updated the answer above. You should be able to rebuild OpenSSL with `MacCatalyst` support by calling:
```bash
git clone git@github.com:marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.git --branch feature/mac-catalyst && cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone && ./build-libssl.sh --archs="MacOSX_x86_64 i386 arm64 armv7s armv7"

```

Comment: Thanks! The script works well with version 1.0.2l. For some reason, it was failing for other versions of Open SSL.

Comment: @marcelosalloum I first tried version 1.0.1e and it kept failing. That gave me a good reason to upgrade to a new version. Thanks again. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @marcelosalloum It fails searching files in "iPhoneSimulator13.2-x86_64.sdk", which now are in "MacOSX10.15-x86_64.sdk". Did not check code but assume this happens when `lipo`a fat lib. `cp -r  "MacOSX10.15-x86_64.sdk" "iPhoneSimulator13.2-x86_64.sdk"` fixes the issue.

Comment: @shallowThought: How do I reproduce this error? It works for me when I run the command option `./build-libssl.sh --archs="MacOSX_x86_64 i386 arm64 armv7s armv7"  --version="1.0.2l"` above. If you share the exact command you've used I can take a look. Please remember that a lipo file can hold only a single binary per architecture, so if you're adding both `MacOSX_x86_64 ` and `x86_64` it won't work.

Comment: @marcelosalloum: this is the command, which we are running from a Xcode build script: `./build-libssl.sh --targets="ios-sim-cross-i386 ios64-cross-arm64 ios-cross-armv7s ios-cross-armv7 mac-catalyst-x86_64" --version="1.1.0"`. I do not mess with lipo, I just guessed that is what's happening in your code. Trying to create a fat lib containing a slice from "iPhoneSimulator13.2-x86_64.sdk", which does not exist. It was only a guess, ignore that part.

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions didn't work for me, so I went on and tried to fix it for my system running Mac OSX 10.15.4.

In my case this is where the above solutions stopped working for me:

```
no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.4.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
```

I read through the build-libssl.sh file noticed that the sdk version was taken by the script using the code:

```
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-version
```

which on my system does return:

```
10.15.4
```

Using finder an navigating to the location:

```
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

did show me there was indeed no MacOSX10.15.4.sdk. There was however a MacOSX10.14.sdk. I did use this knowledge to come up with the following solution:

**OpenSSL version <= 1.0 (1.0.2l)**

> versions <= 1.0 should only use --arch, not --target !

```
git clone git@github.com:marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.git --branch feature/mac-catalyst && \
cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone && \
./build-libssl.sh --arch="MacOSX_x86_64 i386 arm64 armv7s armv7 tv_x86_64 tv_arm64" --macosx-sdk=10.15 --version="1.0.2l"
```

**OpenSSL version >= 1.1 (1.1.0) currently not functional**

> versions >= 1.1 should only use --target, not --arch !

```
git clone git@github.com:marcelosalloum/OpenSSL-for-iPhone.git --branch feature/mac-catalyst && \
cd OpenSSL-for-iPhone && \
./build-libssl.sh --targets="mac-catalyst-x86_64 ios-sim-cross-i386 ios64-cross-arm64 ios-cross-armv7s ios-cross-armv7 tvos-sim-cross-x86_64 tvos64-cross-arm64" --macosx-sdk=10.15 --version="1.1.0" -v
```